# SQL Join different item from one table

Tags: sql

I have a table 
Tablename = table01

```
ID    Item    value
4      a       10
5      b       12
5      c       15
```

and my sql

```
select value as b from table01 where ID = 5 and Item = b
select value as c from table01 where ID = 5 and Item = c
```

How can i join this two sql?

this is my imagine result

```
b     c
12    15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t1.id, t1.value as b, t2.value as c
from table1 t1 join
     table1 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.item = 'b' and t2.item = 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN Item = 'b' THEN value END ) AS b,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Item = 'c' THEN value END ) AS c
  FROM table01;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select max(case when Item = 'b' then value end),
       max(case when Item = 'c' then value end)
from yourtable
Where ID = 5 
  and Item in ( 'b' , 'c')
```

**Note :** This considers that `ID` & `ITEM` combination is not duplicated. If it is duplicated then you will max `value` out of duplicate

Comment: Oh thank you.My SQL is
select max(case when Item = 'b'  and ID =5 then value end),
       max(case when Item = 'c' and ID = 5 then value end),
from table01

it is ok?

Comment: @edwardlim - There was extra comma before `From` clause. Removed it